# Elasticsearch Search Down - SearchPhaseExecutionException

Tags: elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

My server was running fine until I start getting this error for search queries:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures 

{[bgh1FwvvTmydjtDhY-reCA][article-index][3]: 
SearchParseException[[article-index][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"custom_score": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "Arvi", "fields": ["text", "title^3", "domain"]}}, "script": "_score * (1.000008**(doc[\'articleid\'].value*50000.0/100000.0))"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[article-index] [custom_score] the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting disabled]; }

{[bgh1FwvvTmydjtDhY-reCA][article-index][4]: SearchParseException[[article-index][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"custom_score": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "Arvi", "fields": ["text", "title^3", "domain"]}}, "script": "_score * (1.000008**(doc[\'articleid\'].value*50000.0/100000.0))"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[article-index] [custom_score] the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting disabled]; }

{[bgh1FwvvTmydjtDhY-reCA][article-index][1]: SearchParseException[[article-index][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"custom_score": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "Arvi", "fields": ["text", "title^3", "domain"]}}, "script": "_score * (1.000008**(doc[\'articleid\'].value*50000.0/100000.0))"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[article-index] [custom_score] the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting disabled]; }

{[bgh1FwvvTmydjtDhY-reCA][article-index][2]: SearchParseException[[article-index][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"custom_score": {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "Arvi", "fields": ["text", "title^3", "domain"]}}, "script": "_score * (1.000008**(doc[\'articleid\'].value*50000.0/100000.0))"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[article-index] [custom_score] the script could not be loaded]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting disabled]; }]'
)
```

I do not understand what has been changed.
Using pyelasticsearch, this is the query being pushed

```
    bodyquery = {

        "custom_score": {
            "script" : "_score * ("+str(1.0+recency)+"**(doc['articleid'].value*50000.0/"+maxarticleid+"))",
            "query": {
                    "query_string": {"query": keywordstr, "fields": ["text", "title^3", "domain"]}
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Enabled dynaic scripting and its working. Why was it working earlier, and suddenly it stopped.
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

If I am referring to you error log then parse error in your elasticsearch query dsl.

as below:-

```
"script": "_score * (1.000008**(doc[\'articleid\'].value*50000.0/100000.0))"
```

Should be:

```
"script": "_score * (1.000008**(doc['articleid'].value*50000.0/100000.0))"
```

Remove extra backslashes from query.

Comment: Nope. Even with keeping "script": "_score", there is an error